# I have a Java App running in JRE 6 but not in JRE 7. How do i run the application in JRE7

Tags: java, jar, jnlp

I have a JNLP application which runs in JRE6 and not in JRE7. Is there a method to make it run in JRE7? How to filter out all the deprecated methods from the application??

Comment: You can't filter out deprecated methods; you'd have to rewrite the app to use recommended replacements.  You should be using JDK 8; both versions 6 and 7 have passed the end of their support lives.

Answer (score 0):

There is no chance to do this, but you can run the application with Java 6. Just link your java command to use java 6 instead java 7. Or you deinstall java 7 and install Java 6.

I always have some different java version installed (SDK+JRE) to test my applications. Setting the PATH could help.

Or you compile the entire app with JDK 7 instead 6. Then it could be used with JRE 7.

- [Setting Java Path variable](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Answer (score 0):

1.) What is the error you are getting? We can't help you if you don't provide any details! (You can see the error in the java console if you enable it)
[image]

2.)
The error is probably due to the increased security mechanisms/checks added to java. If you really need to use java 1.6 then specify that version in your jnlp file, e.g.

```
<j2se version="1.6*" java-vm-args="-Xmx32m" max-heap-size="32m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
```

3.)
How is you java security configured? 
[image: java security settings]

4.) Is your app signed?

5.) Did you try to add the url to your exception site list?
[image]